# Notification when an app/site gets published to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to subscribe to a sort of notification whenever the website that we're working on gets published to Azure? By publish I mean whenever we use Visual Studio to upload the site to Azure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you setup a continuos delivery.

More info in here:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/aspnet-4-ci-cd-azure-automatic

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2016/12/19/sending-email-notification-from-vststfs-build/

Comment: Is there anything not TFS related? I am not using TFS.